# Javascript Scoping Confusion

Tags: javascript

I couldn't find an exact match on my issue, though many javascript scoping questions do exist. Here is my current code for the question.

```
var my_var = "blank";
var MyFunc = function() {
    my_var = "one";
    //var my_var = "two";
}
alert(my_var);
MyFunc();
alert(my_var);
```

When I run this, I am alerted with **"blank"** and then **"one"** as expected. However, if I uncomment that one line, so it looks like this.

```
var my_var = "blank";
var MyFunc = function() {
    my_var = "one";
    var my_var = "two";
}
alert(my_var);
MyFunc();
alert(my_var);
```

I am alerted with **"blank"** and then **"blank"**. This is not what I would expect and I find it confusing that adding a line will remove behavior. Can anyone explain what is going on here? I am seeing this behavior in both firefox and safari.

Comment: Yet another good reason why ever using local variables with the same name as global variables is just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All `var` statements are effectively "hoisted" up to the top of their enclosing function (sort of).  Thus, the fact that you've got `var my_var` *anywhere* in that function means that all mentions of "my_var" refer to the local variable.

(I said "sort of" because the assignment part of the `var` statement isn't shifted; just the declaration that the identifier should be a local variable.)

Comment: To finish your sentence.  The hoisting makes `my_var` a local variable inside the entire function.

Comment: The spec makes it pretty clear. Section 12.2.  The spec talks about variables being "created", and that's the "hoisting" part.

Comment: also see http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting. +1

Comment: Here's one description of hoisting (there are many others with a Google search): http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-javascript-hoisting-explained/

Answer (score 3):

The reason is because declarations are hoisted within a function's scope in JavaScript. Read more about it [here](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting).

Answer (score 1):

Javascript variables have function scope unlike C, C++, Java, and C# that have block scope (curly brace).

Quick Tip: JavaScript Hoisting Explained

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-javascript-hoisting-explained/